# How do I access the formData in this request via node?

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, body-parser

I am making a request using this code:

```
 Request {
  url: 'http://localhost:10002/asset/upload'
  method: 'POST'
  formData:
    filename: fileName
    code: imageCode
    type: 'raw'
    event_id: eventId
    file: fs.createReadStream(filePath)
    slug: "testing-the-stuff"
```

In my express application I have a route like so:

```
  app.post "/asset/upload", (req, res, next) ->
    assetController.upload req, res, next
```

And a controller that looks like:

```
exports.upload = (req, res, next) ->
  console.log req.body
  res.json 'upload'
```

Everything works fine and does not fail, but the body is always empty? I am not sure if there is a different way for me to access `"formData"`

For reference I am using `bodyparser`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered after some research that bodyparser can not handle multipart form data. TO resolve this I simply replaced bodyparser with busboy-body-parser

```
busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser')
app.use busboyBodyParser()
```

This library seems to combine bodyparsers normal form parsing with busboys ability to handle multipart formdata and files.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy-body-parser